# Error 42P01: relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, schema, pgadmin

I'm new at creating databases, and this error has me dumbfounded, as I am super new with DB admin things (I mostly do reporting type queries). I created a new database through pgAdmin3 GUI, and I'm trying to create DB objects in there using SQL but am getting a:

> ```
> ERROR: relation "replays" does not exist
> SQL state: 42P01
> ```

I looked through the manual but did not find anything very helpful, though I suspect it may have to do with `search_path` somehow. Here is a screenshot. Any idea what I'm doing wrong please?

[image: 42P01]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you had originally was a correct syntax - for *tables*, not for *schemas*.  As you did not have a table (dubbed 'relation' in the error message), it threw the not-found error.

I see you've already noticed this - I believe there is no better way of learning than to fix our own mistakes ;)

But there is something more.  What you are doing above is too much on one hand, and not enough on the other.

Running the script, you

1. create a schema
2. create a role
3. grant `SELECT` *on all tables in the schema* created in (1.) to this new role_
4. and, finally, grant all privileges (`CREATE` and `USAGE`) on the new schema to the new role

The problem lies within point (3.)  You granted privileges on tables in `replays` - but there are no tables in there!  There might be some in the future, but at this point the schema is completely empty.  This way, the `GRANT` in (3.) does nothing - this way you are doing too much.

But what about the future tables?

There is a command for covering them: [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).  It applies not only to tables, but:

> Currently *[as of 9.4]*, only the privileges for tables (including views and foreign tables), sequences, functions, and types (including domains) can be altered.

There is one important limitation, too:

> You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.

This means that a table created by `alice`, who is neither you nor a role than you are a member of (can be checked, for example, by using `\du` in `psql`), will not take the prescribed access rights.  The optional `FOR ROLE` clause is used for specifying the 'table creator' role you are a member of.  In many cases, this implies it is a good idea to create all database objects using the same role - like `mydatabase_owner`.

A small example to show this at work:

```
CREATE ROLE test_owner; -- cannot log in
CREATE SCHEMA replays AUTHORIZATION test_owner;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA replays TO test_owner;

SET ROLE TO test_owner; -- here we change the context, 
                        -- so that the next statement is issued as the owner role

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA replays GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO alice;

CREATE TABLE replays.replayer (r_id serial PRIMARY KEY);

RESET ROLE; -- changing the context back to the original role

CREATE TABLE replays.replay_event (re_id serial PRIMARY KEY);

-- and now compare the two

\dp replays.replayer
                                   Access privileges
 Schema  │   Name   │ Type  │       Access privileges       │ Column access privileges 
─────────┼──────────┼───────┼───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────
 replays │ replayer │ table │ alice=r/test_owner           ↵│ 
         │          │       │ test_owner=arwdDxt/test_owner │ 

\dp replays.replay_event
                               Access privileges
 Schema  │     Name     │ Type  │ Access privileges │ Column access privileges 
─────────┼──────────────┼───────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────
 replays │ replay_event │ table │                   │
```

As you can see, `alice` has no explicit rights on the latter table.  (In this case, she can still `SELECT` from the table, being a member of the `public` pseudorole, but I didn't want to clutter the example by revoking the rights from `public`.)

Answer (score 2):

I talked to someone who helped me find the answer. The correct syntax is, for anyone in future reference. The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-grant.html) mentions it, although it can be easy to miss.

```
START TRANSACTION;
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS replays CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA replays;
CREATE ROLE admins WITH
    PASSWORD 'changeme';
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA replays TO PUBLIC;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA replays TO admins;
COMMIT;
```